# What is the difference between modified and changed file status returned by IndexDiff?

Tags: git, jgit

I found only that:

// in repo, in index, content diff => changed
// in index, in workdir, content differs => modified

But I can't understand the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the javadoc for the getters in class IndexDiff:

```
/**
 * @return list of files changed from tree to index
 */
public Set<String> getChanged()
```

these are the files which differ between the tree HEAD points at (the tip of your current branch in most cases) and the Git index

```
/**
 * @return list of files modified on disk relative to the index
 */
public Set<String> getModified()
```

these are the files which differ between the files on disk (aka working tree) and the Git index

Answer (score 1):

there's not much of elaboration in the command javadoc.
i used the [git status unit-tests](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/StatusCommandTest.java) to understand how **git status** really works.

in short:

> modified - what you get if you modify an existing file without adding it to the index
>
> changed - what you get if you modify an existing file and call 'git add ...' on it

Comment: This is not an actual answer.

Comment: forgot to add the actual definitions, re-edited, thanks @ppperry

Answer (score 0):

since you did not get any answer, I'm giving you a start.

First, I think there is a difference between:

- the work directory : this is the file system you're working on. When you modify a file, that's changed on the file system. Usually, that's the OS work to keep it up-to-date.
- the index : what Git uses to know what's going on. That's Git internal mechanism to keep track of what happens. Even though it's a bit fuzzy for me, it should either know the changes on the file system or the changes you added (with git add [-u]), or the changes you committed (or all of them)
- the repository/local copy : different places where you might have different versions of files. Git uses hashes to keep information about them (but you should know about it if you ask that question)

I know a problem of Git is to deal with the size of a repo, it becomes slow when repo size is pretty huge. More precisely, their team is working on reducing the amount of lstat calls to update Git's knowledge of your file system (so it means Git usually knows when you modify a file on your work directory)

I don't know what you're looking at, but you might search for git-update-index (I think it's called when you do a git add), 'Git lstat' or this kind of stuff on google.

And, sorry about it, but your question is really not clear : too many abbreviations and too few lines. Does 'content diff' means you ran the diff command on your content or that content differs? your symbols are not clear, why use // when you probably list items, and does => represent a consequence, or anything else. People take time to search doc before answering, please take time to write clear questions.

I hope this will help you

Vincent